# Route53 Unable to Resolve Host

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

A few months back I transferred mattymil.com from GoDaddy to Route53 and elected to use AWS nameservers as part of the configuration (config listed below). I recently stood up a test AWS ec2 instance running apache with the default configuration at http://54.204.107.175/ and I can successfully access the default page via the IP. I added an A record to the above mentioned zone pointing to this IP and after several hours it still does not resolve. In addition dig returns no  Answer but dig +trace routes all the way back to the AWS name servers configured in my zone (results listed below). I have exhausted all options I can think of at this point. Anyone have a suggestion on further troubleshooting to get to the root of the problem?

Thanks

**Zone Records**

```
Name: mattymil.com.
Type: A
Value: 54.204.107.175
TTL: 300

Name: mattymil.com.
Type: NS
Value: ns-565.awsdns-06.net. 
ns-1224.awsdns-25.org. 
ns-417.awsdns-52.com. 
ns-1898.awsdns-45.co.uk.
TTL: 172800

Name: mattymil.com.
Type: SOA
Value: ns-565.awsdns-06.net. awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com. 1 7200 900 1209600 86400
TTL: 900
```

**Dig Results**

```
Matt-MBA:~ matty$ dig mattymil.com

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> mattymil.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: FORMERR, id: 61472
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;mattymil.com.          IN  A

;; Query time: 2565 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.15.101#53(192.168.15.101)
;; WHEN: Thu Nov  5 17:02:07 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 30
```

**Dig +Trace Results**

```
Matt-MBA:~ matty$ dig +trace mattymil.com

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> +trace mattymil.com
;; global options: +cmd
.           511022  IN  NS  b.root-servers.net.
.           511022  IN  NS  k.root-servers.net.
.           511022  IN  NS  h.root-servers.net.
.           511022  IN  NS  m.root-servers.net.
.           511022  IN  NS  j.root-servers.net.
.           511022  IN  NS  e.root-servers.net.
.           511022  IN  NS  i.root-servers.net.
.           511022  IN  NS  l.root-servers.net.
.           511022  IN  NS  g.root-servers.net.
.           511022  IN  NS  a.root-servers.net.
.           511022  IN  NS  c.root-servers.net.
.           511022  IN  NS  f.root-servers.net.
.           511022  IN  NS  d.root-servers.net.
;; Received 508 bytes from 192.168.15.101#53(192.168.15.101) in 67 ms

Matt-MBA:~ matty$ clear

Matt-MBA:~ matty$ dig +trace mattymil.com

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> +trace mattymil.com
;; global options: +cmd
.           494953  IN  NS  c.root-servers.net.
.           494953  IN  NS  l.root-servers.net.
.           494953  IN  NS  e.root-servers.net.
.           494953  IN  NS  g.root-servers.net.
.           494953  IN  NS  d.root-servers.net.
.           494953  IN  NS  b.root-servers.net.
.           494953  IN  NS  k.root-servers.net.
.           494953  IN  NS  a.root-servers.net.
.           494953  IN  NS  i.root-servers.net.
.           494953  IN  NS  f.root-servers.net.
.           494953  IN  NS  h.root-servers.net.
.           494953  IN  NS  j.root-servers.net.
.           494953  IN  NS  m.root-servers.net.
;; Received 508 bytes from 192.168.15.101#53(192.168.15.101) in 37 ms

com.            172800  IN  NS  a.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  b.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  c.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  d.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  e.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  f.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  g.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  h.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  i.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  j.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  k.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  l.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  m.gtld-servers.net.
;; Received 490 bytes from 199.7.83.42#53(199.7.83.42) in 2798 ms

mattymil.com.       172800  IN  NS  ns-565.awsdns-06.net.
mattymil.com.       172800  IN  NS  ns-417.awsdns-52.com.
mattymil.com.       172800  IN  NS  ns-1224.awsdns-25.org.
mattymil.com.       172800  IN  NS  ns-1898.awsdns-45.co.uk.
;; Received 199 bytes from 192.5.6.30#53(192.5.6.30) in 1733 ms

;; Received 30 bytes from 205.251.194.53#53(205.251.194.53) in 104 ms
```

Comment: Are you sure you have the right AWS name servers for the zone (the ones that show in the right part of the screen when you select zone name in th e Route53 Hosted zones list)

Comment: It was a concern of mine, how would I verify? The dig trace resolves to the same ones in my zone configuration on the AWS console.

Answer (score 13):

Check this:

1. Log in to your AWS web console
2. Select Route53 service
3. Select Hosted Zones in the left pane
4. Select mattymil.com (but do not click on the domain name, just select the radio button)
5. Notice the 4 name servers in the right pane.
6. Next, go to domain registrar site (in your case stay in Route53), log in and configure name servers for your domain. In Route53: select 'Registered domains' in the left pane, click on your domain name, verify that in the upper right you have name servers from step 5, if they don't exactly match, click 'Add/Edit Name servers' and enter name servers from step 5)

Comment: gandi.net is the underlying registrar when you use Route 53's domain registration services, so you don't contact Gandi directly.  In this case what needs to match is the name servers assigned by Route 53 Hosted Zones, and the name servers in Route 53 Registered Domains.  They are not tightly coupled and if you set them incorrectly, Route 53 doesn't stop you because it assumes you know what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I did not know that about gandi, I'll update the answer

Comment: It's always that thing you took for granted. Thank you, sir.

Comment: I did delete an old hosted zone with old DNS entries. Since I thought hey why not go fast through all? However that did give me a hard time since my NS "on" my domain was different from the NS in my hosted zone. This answer did help me to figure out where my problem was, thanks to you!

Answer (score 3):

@sqlbot pointed me in the right direction.

> gandi.net is the underlying registrar when you use Route 53's domain registration services, so you don't contact Gandi directly. In this case what needs to match is the name servers assigned by Route 53 Hosted Zones, and the name servers in Route 53 Registered Domains. They are not tightly coupled and if you set them incorrectly, Route 53 doesn't stop you because it assumes you know what you are doing.

In route53 registered domains the name servers were different form the NS record in the Zone config. I simply copied the name servers from the NS record into the registered domains name server fields. Within 30 seconds the URL was resolving to the web server.

Answer (score 0):

You need a wait till global dns will update info. easy way to test, use one of your ec2 instances, flush dns, then dig or nslookup.

Comment: thanks. EC2 instance cache is flushed (actually caching is turned off) but dig still returns no answer.